# Error while installing Tk Execute command

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to install Tk-ExecuteCommand package which i downloaded from CPAN.

While installing i am getting this error.

```
sait109@debian:~/Desktop/Tk-ExecuteCommand-1.6$ sudo make
make: Warning: File `/usr/lib/perl/5.10/Config.pm' has modification time 2.3e+07 s in the future
Makefile out-of-date with respect to /usr/lib/perl/5.10/Config.pm /usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE/config.h /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0/Tk/Config.pm
Cleaning current config before rebuilding Makefile...
make -f Makefile.old clean > /dev/null 2>&1
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
/home/sait109/Desktop/Tk-ExecuteCommand-1.6 does not start with /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0
i.e. building outside Tk itself
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Tk::ExecuteCommand
==> Your Makefile has been rebuilt. <==
==> Please rerun the make command.  <==
false
make: *** [Makefile] Error 1
```

Does anyone knows a fix for this. Help pls..

Comment: When in doubt, run `make clean`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of that message is

```
make: Warning: File `/usr/lib/perl/5.10/Config.pm' has modification time 2.3e+07 s in the future
Makefile out-of-date with respect to /usr/lib/perl/5.10/Config.pm /usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE/config.h /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0/Tk/Config.pm
```

Your local timestamps are screwed up, causing `make` to be confused as various targets in the `Makefile` depend on the `/usr/lib/perl/5.10/Config.pm` from the future.

Fix the timestamps on your system or your system clock, depending on which is wrong, and things will be fine.

Additionally, you're seeing warnings for having a locale `en` configured, but not installed. I'm not aware of any locale by that name existing. You might've meant something like `en_US.UTF-8`, which you'll also have to install, once configured. However, this is unrelated to the error you're getting.

Comment: Problem is with the local time stamp only... I adjusted the system time and now it is working fine... Thank you so much Rafl